# XKB - Clearing locked modifiers

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've been having some trouble creating a custom keymap with XKB configuration. I would like to have a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key that locks when called with a specific modifier and can be pressed again to toggle the modifier. I can use the `LockMods()` action to hold down a modifiers but I cannot find any way to unlock to modifier afterwards.

Does the XKB configuration provide a way to clear a specific modifier?

I've include below what I've come up with so far in my xkb_symbols section.

```
key <LFSH> { 
    type = "FOUR_LEVEL",
    symbols[group1] = [ Shift_L, Shift_L, Shift_L, Shift_L ],
    actions[group1] = [ 
        LatchMods(modifiers=Shift),
        NoAction(),
        LockMods(modifiers=Shift), 
        SetMods(modifiers=Shift, clearLocks=true) ]
};
```